# Minecraft Java 1.12.2 Server Spigot Plugin error

Tags: java, minecraft

I need help with a Minecraft server plugin, my server is giving me an error of 
`` Cannot find main class `harvey.plugin.jmsg.JoinMsg' `` and heres my Plugin.yml:

```
main: harvey.plugin.jmsg.JoinMsg
version: 10.1
author: harvey
commands:
```

and here is my plugin its self

```
package harvey.plugin.jmsg;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class JoinMsg extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        String joianquitmsg = null;
        File joinquitmsg = new File("/CJAL/msg.txt");
        Scanner msginfo = new Scanner(joinquitmsg);
        e.setJoinMessage(joianquitmsg);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerQuit(PlayerQuitEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        e.setQuitMessage(getName() + "Welcome!");
    }
}
```

is anyone can help me that would be amazing! 
I'm new to this so any tips aswell would be helpfull! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your probably exporting it wrong in your IDE

try exporting the src and plugin.yml ONLY